# Project building with VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, build, windows-services, projects-and-solutions

I'm using v.s 2008 with c#. 
I have a windows service. I stoped that service and do some changes in the codes. I want to build my project but the visual studio open "save as" window. How can i build my project again?

Comment: What file is it asking you to save?  Have you added a new file to your solution, which VS needs to save before it can build it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you also mention what text the title of the "Save As" window contains.

Comment: No i didnt add any new file. I can build without  changes but when i m changing some codes i cant build. And i m continue save as window but i have an alert like "the operation could not be completed".

Comment: And i m working on a .cs file

Comment: Is one of the files Visual Studio writes before compiling write-protected / locked? In that case, it will usually pop up the SaveFileDialog.

Answer (score 0):

a not really good solution to this problem might be saving that file to some location other than where the current project is, than close & restart visual studio again. If your file is not in the project, you can easily add it.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to one of two reasons.

1. The file in question is read only -
   this can be due to it being checked
   in if under source control.
2. The service file being in use.

Use InstallUtil from the VisualStudio command prompt to uninstall the service before building and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

taken from: [Save File As dialog problem in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415834/save-file-as-dialog-problem-in-visual-studio-2008)

Make sure you are running Visual Studio as an Adminstrator. To do this, create a Desktop Short cut for Visual Studio 2008. Right click on it, and select Properties. Then select the Compatibility tab. At the bottom under Priviledge Level, make sure Run the program as an adminstrator is checked. Select the OK button. Start Vis Studio again

Also, try this

1) Open the Visual Studio command prompt 
2) Then run the following : devenv /ResetSettings

Regards,

EL