# Save File As dialog problem in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

I am programming via Visual Studio 2008. I change my html page and save it using Ctrl + S and then hit Ctrl+F5 on the browser to test it. My problem is when I save my file in VS after refreshing the browser, "Save File As" dialog appears and when I want to save it with that file name, an error dialog appears which says file exists!!!. I am doing this every time in my company which uses Windows 2003 and Windows XP, but there I have no problem. At home I am using Windows 7, and this error is killing me.

Comment: You've got the rights to save the file? 
Are you running VS in administrator mode?
Is the file locked for some reason? (use processexplorer to see if a process has it locked)

Comment: It's ok when I save the html page in VS regularly, but when I refresh FF for example to test the page, and then continue editing in VS and save it with Ctrl+S immediately, the dialog appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem
My C# projects were all under XPsp3
I installed Win7, then Vis Studio 8 SP1 and the rest of my development tools.
Opened up my C# projects and got the Save As problem. , try this, it worked for me.

Make sure you are running Visual Studio as an Adminstrator.
To do this, create a Desktop Short cut for Visual Studio 2008.
Right click on it, and select Properties.
Then select the Compatibility tab.
At the bottom under Priviledge Level, make sure Run the program as an adminstrator is checked.
Select the OK button.
Start Vis Studio again

Also, try this

1) Open the Visual Studio command prompt
2) Then run  the following :  devenv /ResetSettings.

Comment: devenv /ResetSettings did the trick. The rest is just obviously not the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Using VS 2008 Express SP1 under Vista I had the same problem.  I was running IE9 and it's debugger.  Closing IE9 debugger allowed the save.  This typically did not happen.