# Visual Studio 2008 "Save File As" Dialog Intermittent Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe, windows-7-x64, savefiledialog

Me and a few of my coworkers are experiencing an odd issue in Visual Studio 2008 and Windows 7 (64-bit).  We use VSS6 for our source control (unfortunately).

We have an issue where we will make a change to a checked-out file, resulting in the file getting checked out as expected.  But when we go to build the project, or try to save the file, it will often (but not always) prompt us with the "Save File As" dialog, as if VS thinks the file is checked-in (and thus has the read-only flag set).

However, all we have to do is cancel out of the dialog and save or build again, and it will always work the second time, without prompting the save as dialog.  Or, we can go through with the save as, leaving the name the same, and it will work.  It's as if the source control status in VS2008 hasn't caught up w/ VSS (even though we VS2008 was the app that checked the file out).

This is similar to the discussion on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415834/save-file-as-dialog-problem-in-visual-studio-2008), but it's not an issue of permissions or running as administrator, 1) because it resolves itself on second attempt, and 2) we're already running VS as administrator.

Thanks in advance.

Jerad

Answer (score 0):

One thing I had trouble with under Windows 7 and SCM (even with SVN) was the auto-indexing feature. Make sure you have it turned off for the folders that contain your source code. I don't have any evidence it causes problems for VSS  but it seems like as fragile as VSS is, having it turned on will almost certainly be problematic.

*BTW, you do know that working for a company that uses VSS, is grounds for being barred from StackOverflow for life, right?*

Comment: And rightfully so!  Fortunately, we've since moved away from using VSS, and have graduated to the shiny brand new VS 2010 and TFS. :)